# Kubernetes service (load balancer) doesnt work with custom domain name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a kubernetes service I exposed with a custom domain name. When I try to access the service using custom domain, it fails (just loading forever). But if I use the IP, it works. Do I need to configure something somewhere? I am using GKE.

When I ping the URL, its trying to hit the correct IP. Also ping works.

Comment: So you can ping the service using both IP and domain name but can only access it using IP - is that right ?

Comment: Did you add your IP address as loadBalancerIP in your service manifest? Are you using a static IP address? if so, did you [update](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip#step_4_configure_your_domain_name_records) your DNS records of your domain name? Did you create an A DNS record for your domain?

Comment: @WojciechBogacz yes. Ping works both for IP and domain name

Comment: @WojciechBogacz seems like it works now ... Didnt change anything tho lols...

Answer (score 1):

The LoadBalance service is a layer 4 load balancer and thus only uses the IP to route traffic to your backend pods. If ping works and the site loads correctly when you use the IP address, this shows that the load balancer is directing traffic correctly.

There is likely a setting in your webserver that is looking at the URL and is having issues loading when a URL is used. Check your container logs to see if any errors are returned when you use a URL instead of IP.

Comment: I believe @Patrick W is right - check the configuration - for example if you are using Nginx you can have a look at the server_name variable - it it's set to the servers' IP then try to put in a domain name there, restart nginx and try again.